# Can we launch navigation drawer without using ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, drawer

Can we launch navigation drawer without using `ActionBarDrawerToggle`?  In my implementation, I do not want to use action bar.

So, I don't want `ActionBarDrawerToggle` to open and close the drawer.  I want to open the navigation drawer when hardware menu button is clicked.

I am targeting Android 2.2 and using support library v4.

As per my understanding, `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class will have implementation internally to handle the opening and closing of navigation drawer.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to open the navigation drawer when hardware menu button is clicked

Not every Android device has a MENU button, so you better have some other solution beyond just that.

Also, using MENU to open a navigation drawer, instead of a menu -- may be viewed as odd behavior by some of your users.

> I am targeting Android 2.2 and using support library v4.

If you are using `DrawerLayout`, it has `openDrawer()` and `closeDrawer()` methods that you can use that will open the drawer and close the drawer, respectively.

Comment: I have supplied my list view as parameter to the openDrawer method and it worked.  All my target devices have menu button and this is my requirement.  Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 8):

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ImageView ivNavigationIcon = //some image or button or menu what ever you want
ivNavigationIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
});
```